# Inductor current ripple ratio of buck boost converters

Tags: buck-boost, ripple-current

I have a question about this paper: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1210630

I have always thought that the maximum current ripple of a buck converter occurs with a duty cycle of 0.5. The paper on page 1373 shows in figure 3(a) that the maximum current ripple occurs at a duty cycle of about 0.6. Does this mean that the current ripple does not always reach its maximum value at a duty cycle of 0.5 or did the author make a mistake or did I misunderstand the diagram?

Comment: 1. The article you linked to is behind a paywall. 2. The chart doesn't seem to say anything about buck converters. All the traces are labeled with the names of different kinds of converters.

Comment: The trace half-bridge is the one. Between a voltage ration 0 - 1 it operates as a buck converter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The author has assumed a constant input current and input voltage (in this case the bus current and voltage). With this assumption, the current ripple curves and the equations in the paper are correct.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

[image]

I don't think these accurate without all the other variables like DCR, RdsOn ESR on both Caps, battery ESR, and load impedance.

I simulated a 75 to 250kW Half-bridge and the ripple current was negligible compared to the DC current at high load. I used an almost ideal SPDT switch so I did not need diodes.

I tried open loop with Duty cycle control and crude negative feedback with an RCRC divider and Offset V in the ramp comparator operating at 20kHz to get 150~300V in and 300V out.

With this arrangement the half-bridge showed little or no sensitivity to duty cycle for Inductor ripple as the load current was high. Meaning operating in CCM mode.

Perhaps these are NO-LOAD and I did not understand the question.
[image]

Comment: The author has neglected the losses, as in the paper he compared the topologies. I am surprised that in your simulation the current ripple did not change with the duty cycle.

Comment: I suspect that was due to negative feedback  with variable DC input voltage, FWIW @Noah